# Wild rice and Pesach

Tags: halacha, passover, kitniyos-semigrain-legume

Wild rice (AKA as crazy oats) contrary to its names is not in fact rice or oats. It is in fact a member of the same tribe as rice but is a different genus. According to Wikipedia they're nut directly related. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wild_rice. Since it ms not rice and did not exist in Europe is this kitnyot? Is there a minhag which added on wild rice as kitnyot? Or is this like quinoa (which many hold was not part of the original minhag and so is fine) ?

Comment: Looks like it is just a different breed of rice. Rice is itself a kind of grass. So is wheat for that matter. And corn and millet. This is in the tribe Orizeae which contains kinds of Orez=rice.

Comment: @double AA it's true they share the same tribe but they're still different genuses. Wikipedia calls them not directly but closely related.

Comment: the point is more that none of that linnean taxonomy matters at all. They're clearly a rice. It's nothing like quinoa which is a berry, not even a grass. It doesn't matter if regular rice and it technically share a genus, family, or species.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83189/discussion-between-orion-and-double-aa).